# Curl error with mink behat on vagrant VM

Tags: php, curl, vagrant, behat, mink

I have a PHP web app developing on a vagrant vm with ubuntu and nginx. The app has been passed on to me with some feature tests using Behat in place but I can't get it running on the vagrant box.

I've installed everything correctly I believe but when I run:

```
bin\behat test.feature
```

I get the following error from curl:

```
[curl] 6: Couldn't resolve host 'site.local' [url] http://site.local:8080/management/login/logout
```

My Behat.yml looks like this:

```
default:
paths:
    features: modules/better-communities-core/features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://site.local:8080'
      selenium2: ~
      goutte: ~
      show_cmd: 'open %s'
```

And for my vagrant settings I have http running on port 8080 rather than standard 80 which is obviously part of the issue.

It may be I need to change some network settings to my local machine (rather than the vm) or I may need to do something on the VM. I've tried various problem solving like defining the curl port in the goutte settings, I can't find a way of doing this for selenium2.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
 base_url: 'http://site.local:8080'
```

with:

```
base_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
```

Comment: That definitely looks like it may have solved it. Do you have any explanation?

Comment: site.local cannot be resolved to an ip-address because it's not in your hosts file :-)

Comment: I thought I'd set it up as a host tbh. I'm in the process of switching to nginx from apache so may have done something wrong though as I don't have too much experience with it.